# Is there a word to describe someone that receives a bill?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a client of mine offers their services, they have to determine to whom to send the bill. Is there a word to describe that person/organization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not in many dictionaries I've often heard the word [***invoicee***](http://www.cen.eu/cwa/bii/specs/Profiles/DesignDoc/BII%20Glossary.pdf): *one who receives the invoice.*

You might also just refer to them as *the Buyer* or *the Purchaser*

Comment: Often the person buying goods is not the person who pays for them, as many parents have discovered.

Answer (score 8):

They would be the *[recipient](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recipient)* of the bill.

Answer (score 4):

You might refer to *responsible party*, to the *[payer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/payer)* ("One who pays; specifically, the person by whom a bill or note has been, or should be, paid"),  or conceivably to the *[debtor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/debtor)* ("A person or firm that owes money; one in debt; one who owes a debt").  Online payment forms often have a section for *billing address* information that can include the name of the party responsible for payment.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the common billing term: Responsible Party.